# What are ".~bpl" files?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, bpl

Using Code Gear Delphi 2007 (don't know if it matter), each time a ".bpl" package is compiled, a ".~bpl" file is created too.
What are ".~bpl" files? Are those files required or is there a way to avoid their creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the backup of the previous copy of the BPL file, just like the `.~pas` files are backups of the .pas files and the `.~dsk` file is a previous copy of your desktop settings file and the `.~dfm` is a previous copy of your .dfm file.

There's no way to avoid their creation, but they're harmless. I'm not sure why they would concern you, but you can always create a post-build event in your project to delete them after a successful build.